# Release file from RichtextBox LoadFile Method

Tags: c#, file-io, richtextbox

So, I load a file at the start of a form. I have "Save button" in that form.When I click it, I want to overwrite the file with richtextbox.Savefile method. but I get "Access to path.. is denied"

I checked and got this:

1. Permissions for current user are all granted
2. The debug folder has "Read-Only" -- tried to remove, but they always come back

Now, I think that the program doesn't release the resource(the file) only when I close the form

Is there any method to force this? (I think the file remains loaded into the RAM memory)

One more thing: I must use SaveFile and LoadFile methods. I am working with RTF files and my code is in such a way that this methods do the best job.

```
    public EditareArticol(string path,List<capitol>chapters,Object[,]lca)
    {
        this.richTextBoxEx1.LoadFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);
    }

    private void saveToolStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBoxEx1.SaveFile("articles\\" + 
                                textBox1.Text + ".dat",
                                RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText);  
File.SetAttributes("articles\\" + textBox1.Text + ".dat", File.GetAttributes("articles\\" + textBox1.Text + ".dat") | FileAttributes.Hidden);        
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I think it's all about the handle for the specific file.
From the MSDN Documentations:

> The LoadFile method will not open a file until a handle is created for the RichTextBox. Ensure that the control's handle is created before calling the LoadFile method.

Comment: Check if your program has the permissions to write in specified Directory ("articles\\"+textBox1.Text+".dat")

Comment: it has... Visual Studio 2012 is creating at the start of the program the folder ("articles") and then downloads several files in it...so it has the permissions

Comment: You should create the file before you use `RichTextBox.SaveFile(String string)` to save the contents of the file.  I assure you there are much better ways to save RTF other then these two functions.

Comment: @LuciC - You made no mention that the file you are attempting to save was downloaded. **Your problem lays with that code.**  Your program I assure you releases the file when the program is closed it doesn't have a choice in the matter.

Comment: For testing purpose, try to do it (RichTextBox.SaveFile()) exactly as posted in Microsoft example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4a710b1.aspx). If it works, then modify your code correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED:
the program didn't let me to overwrite the files because they were having HIDDEN attribute
Once I removed that, all start working great.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (file was written the first time, then loaded, but was not saved again the second time). My solution was to use ReadAlltext instead  of LoadFile. I know it is an old question, but I spent a lot of time searching for the solution and could not find clear answers to my issue. I dont know technical stuff but it worked for me and might work for others.

My solution:

```
string path = "whatever...."

// TO SAVE / OVERWRITE :

 richTextBox1.SaveFile(path, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

// TO LOAD:

richTextBox1.Text= File.ReadAllText(path);
```

If you have issues with special letters like ÁÉÕã, you may specify unicode codes to loading method, for example:

```
richTextBox1.Text= File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.UTF7);
```

Valid options are UTF7, UTF8, ASCII, Default, UTF32, Unicode.